# Steam has "forgotten" all of the shared libraries on the device

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

I have a shared library from my friend. I was able to play it fine until today, now it says that that it has to be authorized again on this device and asks to send a request to a friend to do that which in turn fails:
"In order to allow game sharing  the owner must login to this machine..." which they already did of course some time ago. How can this problem be fixed? (Apart from asking a friend to do it again)

Comment: it's probably a timed certificate, the only workaround would be to 'go back in time' aka set your date/clock backwards, but steam connects to the internet so it checks the real-world time, no dice i'm afraid :/

Comment: Well going back in time did not help, I am not so sure it's because of that, perhaps it started thinking that I am on another device, or lost the data somehow. Not sure why though

Comment: It's probably a security measure to discourage from people selling access to their accounts to unrelated persons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out what was the problem. I have turned off one of my network adapters. It seems that to detect the same machine is used you have to have exactly the same network adapters as you had during Family sharing installation.